# What are that symbols mean especilly the red point and the circled phone

Tags: notification-bar

[image]
What are that symbols mean especilly the red point and the circled phone is it a call recorder

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.phonearena.com/image.php?m=Articles.Images&f=name&id=185155&kw=) shows the similar red dot in the notification

Yes, It seems to be call recorder notification.